# I went to bed with a headache vs I slept with a headache

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it idiomatic to say **"I slept with a headache"** as opposed to **"I went to sleep with a headache**"? I'm not sure why but **"sleeping with a headache"** doesn't sound right to me. Can anyone help? I can't understand why it sounds wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is the meaning, not grammar.

When you are asleep, you feel nothing.  You can't have a headache while you are sleeping (unless you have a headache in your dream).  When you are asleep, you are not conscious of pain or anything else.

This is why "sleeping with a headache" seems wrong.

It is fine to say "I went to sleep with a headache".  And I suppose you might say "I slept with a headache" to mean "I went to sleep with a headache, and I still had a headache when I woke up". But that still seems a little strange.

There's no grammar rule to learn here, just that the meaning has to make sense too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wish my question hadn't been downvoted so many times for no reason. Perhaps because it sounded very simple, but it actually wasn't so simple. I couldn't answer the question myself.